# Rails admin from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I am trying to create rails admin without using a gem.

I have a admin login and a namespace. My question is how can I for instance differentiate with user model in admin and outside admin.

Imagine user model has a controller with actions edit update new create. I would like to use the same actions for admin. But do I have to create another controller or should I use the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. It depends on your project and its complexity. The easiest solution will be to add admin column in your User model, something like:

```
    rails generate migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean 
    rails db:migrate
```

and to assign true to admin user from your DB users table. For example first user from your DB. In rails console:

```
rails c
user = User.first  # The console will load first user
user.admin = 1     # It will return true 
user.save          # It will save and assign true to admin user
```

Then you just need to make simple logic in  **application_controller.rb** and call the method `is_admin?` from your views.  ( assuming that you already stored user's id in session hash: `session[:user_id] = user.id` )

```
  helper_method :current_user, :signed_in?, :is_admin?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def signed_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def is_admin?
    signed_in? ? current_user.admin : false
  end
```

There are plenty of other ways, like adding roles, differentiate Admin table from Users table. If you opt for differentiate admin from users table, you need Admin controller, and Admin model as well. I hope I gave you the idea to start.